# Set maximum scrollview

Tags: android

I want to set max scrollview
Because it show unlimited scrollview so i want to limite it

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:id="@id/scroll_container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and disable scrolling if user tries to scroll further than limit that you decided:

```
if(scrollView.scrollY() >= limit)
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

Comment: Where i add it ? Inside this code ?

Comment: @BenaissaAdel in the Java file.

Comment: At any place in ?